# Image does not get uploaded in to AWS S3 Bucket in Java Spring Boot Project

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, cloud

I am trying to upload an image to the **AWS S3 Bucket** using my Spring Boot Application.But the image does not get uploaded and it shows an error in the console.But all my configurations are correct.In here my **awsS3AudioBucketCoverPhoto** is my S3Bucket Name.
This is my AmazonS3Config file.

```
@Configuration
public class AmazonS3Config
{
    @Value("${aws.access.key.id}")
    private String awsKeyId;

    @Value("${aws.access.key.secret}")
    private String awsKeySecret;

    @Value("${aws.region}")
    private String awsRegion;

    @Value("${aws.s3.audio.bucket.cover.photo}")
    private String awsS3AudioBucketCoverPhoto;

    @Value("${aws.s3.audio.bucket.profile.photo}")
    private String awsS3AudioBucketProfilePhoto;

    @Bean(name = "awsKeyId")
    public String getAWSKeyId() {
        return awsKeyId;
    }

    @Bean(name = "awsKeySecret")
    public String getAWSKeySecret() {
        return awsKeySecret;
    }

    @Bean(name = "awsRegion")
    public Region getAWSPollyRegion() {
        return Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(awsRegion));
    }

    @Bean(name = "awsCredentialsProvider")
    public AWSCredentialsProvider getAWSCredentials() {
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(this.awsKeyId, this.awsKeySecret);
        return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials);
    }

    @Bean(name = "awsS3AudioBucketCoverPhoto")
    public String getAWSS3AudioBucketCoverPhoto() {
        return awsS3AudioBucketCoverPhoto;
    }

    @Bean(name = "awsS3AudioBucketProfilePhoto")
    public String getAWSS3AudioBucketProfilePhoto() {
        return awsS3AudioBucketProfilePhoto;
    }
}
```

This my ServiceImpl class code.

```
    @Override
    public String uploadCoverImageToS3Bucket(MultipartFile multipartFileCover, boolean enablePublicReadAccess) {
         String fileName = PathCOVER+multipartFileCover.getOriginalFilename();


        try {
            //creating the file in the server (temporarily)
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(multipartFileCover.getBytes());
            fos.close();

            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(this.awsS3AudioBucketCoverPhoto, fileName, file);

            if (enablePublicReadAccess) {
                putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            }
            this.amazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
            //removing the file created in the server
            file.delete();
        } catch (IOException | AmazonServiceException ex) {
            logger.error("error [" + ex.getMessage() + "] occurred while uploading [" + fileName + "] ");
        }
 return multipartFileCover.getOriginalFilename() + " File uploaded successfully";

    }
```

This is the error it shows in the intellij idea console.

```
error [https:\elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-530228581445.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\CoverPhoto\henna.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)] occurred while uploading [https://elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-530228581445.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/CoverPhoto/henna.jpg]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the [`new PutObjectRequest(String bucketName, String key, File file)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#PutObjectRequest-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-), the first argument is the name of the bucket, the second is the object key.

It seems like your `fileName` which you pass as object key has the value

```
https://elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-530228581445.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/CoverPhoto/henna.jpg
```

Which is clearly not a valid object key.

I can't figure out from your code which value `awsS3AudioBucketCoverPhoto` has, but be sure to check it as well - it has to be the name of the target bucket.

Comment: Yes I  found out the error.Actually the filename was the error.I have added AWS file path [https://elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-530228581445.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/CoverPhoto/    infront of the filename when I am adding new PutObjectRequest(this.awsS3AudioBucketCoverPhoto, fileName, file)

Comment: And my awsS3AudioBucketCoverPhoto is my bucket name which i have already defined in my application.properties file